# Is there a difference in the way Firefox and Chrome handles DNS lookups?

Tags: firefox, browser

I'm having an issue that on the surface looks like simple settings mismatch between two the two browsers: Various websites will not load in firefox, while they work just fine in chrome. Firefox simply yields "Server not found" right away.

Things that I've tried:

- Clear cache, history, and everything else
- Disable any extensions
- Ensure that firefox is set to not using a proxy
- Disable ipv6 via about:config
- Disable DNS prefetch via about:config
- Ensure that my privacy-paranoia hasn't caused me to tamper with any settings that could cause this

I am left thinking that there must be some fundamental differences in the way chrome and firefox tries to set up the request, but I cannot see how and why.

It is perhaps worth noting that the sites that won't load all belong to the same domain, but many other sites on the same domain works fine in both browsers. If I am not mistaken, the common denominator between the ones that won't work is that most (maybe all) of them are hosted via Azure. It is also worth noting that this issue started a couple of weeks ago with no changes done on the server side.

Using Firefox 80 on Linux.

I just tested with a different linux PC with FireFox 76, and it works just fine there.

Comment: DNS over https?

Comment: @SparedWhisle Enabling DNS over HTTPS worked, so that's one step closer to the root cause. The other laptop that has been working fine all along does not have DNSoHTTPS enabled, though.